# How to verify domain ownership via text record check? (like flippa, godaddy, etc)

Tags: dns, txt

I'm looking to start a domain name marketplace for niche domains and need to verify domain ownership when people submit their domains for sale on the site. Similar to the process like Flippa or Godaddy domain auctions, where they give user a domain txt record value to add to their DNS and then they check to make sure the person owns the domain before making the listing active on the marketplace.

Would appreciate if anyone knows how to check a domain txt records to make sure the domain owner has added the txt record. For example, we ask them to submit new txt record "xyz123xyz123xyz123blahblah" and then we can check to make sure they have added the txt record to their domain records.

Sorry, not familiar with txt records and if there is a certain format that is required. Any info on that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for any help on this!

Comment: You check by requesting the txt record and comparing it with the string you expected. Its unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check with `dig example.com txt` on Linux. Most languages should be able to query this. There should be libraries/packages for it as well, so this shouldn't be a problem for your application.

TXT value is just a string, so you can put anything you wish. [Official format](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1464) for the string is with attributes and their values: `verification=qwerty123`. Most DNS servers have a limitation on the size of the string, so you can't put a huge value in it.

More about TXT: https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/dns-records/dns-txt-record/

Comment: "Most DNS servers have a limitation on the size of the string, so you can't put a huge value in it." Yet the standard (RFC 1034/1035) does not put limits really, strings have to. be split in 255 bytes chunk, that is all.